# WaitOneのOneが意味するものは？

Tags: c#

マルチスレッドプログラミングにおいてよく目にする'WaitOne'というメソッド。
この変数名にある'One'とは、何を意味しているのでしょうか？
1（信号・シグナル）を待つ といった意味じゃないかと予想していますが、これは間違いでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WaitHandle`クラスには`WaitOne`、`WaitAll`、`WaitAny`の3つのメソッドグループが定義されていますので、他が複数の`WaitHandle`を待機することを考えると「単独の信号」といった意味でのoneだと思います。

Answer (score 0):

１個の one でしょう。

Win32API では `WaitForSingleObject` と `WaitForMultipleObjects` なんてのもあります。
長ったらしいですが、英語的にはこっちのほうがわかりやすいのかも？
.NET の `WaitAll` `WaitAny` はシンプルで良いですよね。